# Which is faster Select Column names or Select *?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, select

I am writing a Stored Procedure which is joining 3 tables, each table have two Columns.

Query 1 :  `SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].[PersonInfo] P join [dbo].[Receipt] R
            ON   P.Id = R.PersonInfo_Id join [dbo].[Goods] G
            ON   P.Id = G.PersonInfo_Id`

Query 2:     `SELECT P.Id, R.Date, G.Clothes 
            FROM [dbo].[PersonInfo] P join [dbo].[Receipt] R
            ON   P.Id = R.PersonInfo_Id join [dbo].[Goods] G
            ON   P.Id = G.PersonInfo_Id`

I would like to know in terms of query performance which of the above query will return the table columns faster Select * or Select (specifying all the column names)?

Comment: [Always use column names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). It'll actually be slower not to, if the table contains data you do not wish to use in the query.

Comment: Query 3: Remove the redundant `B.Id` and `C.Id` columns.

Comment: What I am trying to say If I want to return all the columns is it better to use  all column names or writtinnig * would be sufficient

Comment: Always use column names, even if you want to return all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is "faster" - if you select every column from every table, and you don't need every column from every table, then `SELECT *` and `SELECT every,single,column` are both equally wasteful. @ypercube makes a good point: columns you've joined on are obviously redundant, so as soon as you've removed just one of those columns from the output list, you've already made at least some aspects of performance more efficient (maybe not the reads, depending on table structure and chosen indexes, but certainly less work for the network and presentation tiers). Never mind if you are pulling LOB data, computed columns, CLR types etc. that you don't ultimately need in the output.

In reality, though, even in cases where you really do need all the columns from a table, there are far worse things that can happen with `SELECT *`, and they don't involve performance. Please read this in full:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)